# Get all the IP addresses for an all email addresses in a table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Lets say we have a table named `record` and it has 3 fields

`id
email
ip`

**Situation**

We have to find out which of the email addresses have used more than 2 IP addresses AND what are those ip addresses. Now if it was only about `COUNT` we simply use

```
SELECT email,COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as C FROM record GROUP BY email HAVING(c>2)
```

But I also need to see those ip addresses. So expected output is like

```
email1@example.com  192.168.0.1
email1@example.com  192.168.0.2
email1@example.com  192.168.0.3
email1@example.com  192.168.0.4
email1@example.com  192.168.0.5

...etc...

email2@example.com  192.168.1.3
email2@example.com  192.168.1.4
email2@example.com  192.168.1.5
```

Any suggestion how to JOIN the table to itself and get the desired output without killing MySQL for 1 million records?

**Note:** Please note that ip is stored as an INT and is indexed. I won't need help with converting that ip back to its string representation, that can be ignored for any practical answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the reply from @Meherzad, but returning the unique ip addresses:-

```
SELECT 
   a.email, 
   a.ipAddress,
   b.cnt
FROM
   (SELECT email, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as cnt
   FROM record 
   GROUP BY email 
   HAVING(c>2))b
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT email, ip
   FROM record) a
ON
   a.email = b.email;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query will return email and its count, but you also need the IP address listed

```
SELECT 
   a.email, 
   a.ipAddress,
   b.cnt
FROM
   (SELECT 
       email,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as cnt
   FROM 
       record 
   GROUP BY 
       email 
   HAVING(c>2))b
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT 
       DISTINCT *
   FROM
       record) a
ON
   a.email = b.email;
```

Comment: This would be my choice, although minor typo in that you refer to the column b.cnt from the subselect but the column name is b.C

Comment: Thanks, but this also returns duplicate IPs. Anyway we could remove those? and only return all the unique ips for every email?

Answer (score 0):

How about subsetting the query (won't work with Views in MySQL, I guess)

```
select * from records where email in (
select email 
from records
group by email
having count(email) > 2)
```

EDIT: Forgot to add the distinct clause for IP, removed IN clause, but then joining with small subset of emails

```
select distinct records.email, ip from records
inner join
(select email 
from records
group by email
having count(email) > 2) as subq
ON subq.email = records.email
```

Comment: 1 million records to start with, and `IN` might be a recipe for disaster

Comment: You might have 1 million records, but `IN` will only have distinct `email`, which would be way less than 1 million. `Join`ing such a table would not make real sense. If number of distinct `email` are huge, maybe we can come up with an optimal solution.